# How to add OpenCV Contour Smoothing to Existing Buffer

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

I'm not a C++ coder originally so most of this code leaves me scratching my head. However, I know it should be fairly simple to add contouring to the following code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="CoordinateMapperHelper.cpp" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// CoordinateMapperHelper.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include "CoordinateMapperHelper.h"
#include <robuffer.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace KinectImageProcessor;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace WindowsPreview::Kinect;
using namespace cv;

CoordinateMapperHelper::CoordinateMapperHelper() :
m_depthPoints(nullptr),
m_coordinateMapper(nullptr),
m_colorHeight(0),
m_colorWidth(0),
m_depthHeight(0),
m_depthWidth(0)
{
    // get active kinect sensor
    KinectSensor^ sensor = WindowsPreview::Kinect::KinectSensor::GetDefault();

    // get coordinatemapper
    m_coordinateMapper = sensor->CoordinateMapper;

    m_depthWidth = sensor->DepthFrameSource->FrameDescription->Width;
    m_depthHeight = sensor->DepthFrameSource->FrameDescription->Height;

    // create color frame description for RGBa format
    FrameDescription^ colorFrameDescription = sensor->ColorFrameSource->CreateFrameDescription(ColorImageFormat::Rgba);

    m_colorWidth = colorFrameDescription->Width;
    m_colorHeight = colorFrameDescription->Height;

    m_depthPoints = ref new Array<DepthSpacePoint>(m_colorWidth * m_colorHeight);
}

bool CoordinateMapperHelper::ProcessMultiFrameBufferData(
    _In_ const Platform::Array<UINT16>^ depthDataArray,
    _In_ Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ colorDataBuffer,
    _In_ const Platform::Array<UINT8>^ bodyIndexframeArray,
    _In_ Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ outputDataBuffer)
{
    if (depthDataArray == nullptr || colorDataBuffer == nullptr || bodyIndexframeArray == nullptr || outputDataBuffer == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // map color coordinates to depth coordinates
    m_coordinateMapper->MapColorFrameToDepthSpace(depthDataArray, m_depthPoints);

    // Get access to color buffer
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> spColorBufferByteAccess;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IInspectable> spColorDataBuffer = reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(colorDataBuffer);
    HRESULT hr = spColorDataBuffer.As(&spColorBufferByteAccess);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Retrieve the color buffer data.
    int* pColorData = nullptr;
    byte* pColorByteData = nullptr;
    hr = spColorBufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pColorByteData);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    pColorData = (int*)pColorByteData;

    // Get access to output buffer
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> spOutputBufferByteAccess;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IInspectable> spOutputDataBuffer = reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(outputDataBuffer);

    hr = spOutputDataBuffer.As(&spOutputBufferByteAccess);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Retrieve the output buffer data.
    int* pOutputData = nullptr;
    byte* pOutputDataByte = nullptr;
    hr = spOutputBufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pOutputDataByte);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    pOutputData = (int*)pOutputDataByte;

    DepthSpacePoint* pDepthPoints = m_depthPoints->Data;
    byte* pBodyIndexFrameArray = bodyIndexframeArray->Data;

    ZeroMemory(pOutputData, outputDataBuffer->Capacity);

    // loop over each color pixel
    int numColorPixels = m_colorWidth * m_colorHeight;
    for (int colorIndex = 0; colorIndex < numColorPixels; ++colorIndex)
    {
        DepthSpacePoint p = pDepthPoints[colorIndex];
        // Infinity means invalid point so we can skip processing on it
        if (p.X != -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() && p.Y != -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
        {
            int depthX = static_cast<int>(p.X + 0.5f);
            int depthY = static_cast<int>(p.Y + 0.5f);

            if ((depthX >= 0 && depthX < m_depthWidth) && (depthY >= 0 && depthY < m_depthHeight))
            {
                BYTE bodyIndexPixel = pBodyIndexFrameArray[depthX + (depthY * m_depthWidth)];

                // if we're tracking a player for the current pixel, copy the pixel from the color data
                if (bodyIndexPixel != 0xff)
                {
                    // pOutputData[colorIndex] = pColorData[colorIndex];
                    pOutputData[colorIndex] = -0xffffff;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    outputDataBuffer->Length = colorDataBuffer->Length;

    return true;
}
```

I'd like the output of the ProcessMultiframeBuffer to have the contour applied. The image is of a persons silloutte but I'd like to smooth the edges as best as I can.

Thanks!

I have the code in C# but i'm having problems porting it.

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.BodyIndexBasics
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class responsible for extracting out the contours of an image.
    /// </summary>
    internal class FindContours
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Method used to process the image and set the output result images.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="colorImage">Source color image.</param>
        /// <param name="thresholdValue">Value used for thresholding.</param>
        /// <param name="processedGray">Resulting gray image.</param>
        /// <param name="processedColor">Resulting color image.</param>
        public void IdentifyContours(Bitmap colorImage, int thresholdValue, bool invert, out Bitmap processedGray, out Bitmap processedColor)
        {
            #region Conversion To grayscale

            BlurBitmapEffect myBlurEffect = new BlurBitmapEffect();

            Image<Gray, byte> grayImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(colorImage);
            Image<Bgr, byte> color = new Image<Bgr, byte>(new Bitmap(colorImage.Width, colorImage.Height));

            #endregion Conversion To grayscale

            #region Image normalization and inversion (if required)

            grayImage = grayImage.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(thresholdValue), new Gray(255));
            if (invert)
            {
                grayImage._Not();
            }

            #endregion Image normalization and inversion (if required)

            #region Extracting the Contours

            using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
            {
                for (Contour<Point> contours = grayImage.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
                {
                    Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.015, storage);
                    if (currentContour.BoundingRectangle.Width > 20)
                    {
                        CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(color, contours, new MCvScalar(255), new MCvScalar(255), -1, 5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, new Point(0, 0));
                    }
                }
            }

            #endregion Extracting the Contours

            #region Asigning output

            processedColor = color.ToBitmap();
            processedGray = grayImage.ToBitmap();

            #endregion Asigning output
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I'm working with the following code as an attempted conversion.

```
outputDataBuffer->Length = colorDataBuffer->Length;

    IplImage * ovImage = NULL;
    ovImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(1920, 1080), 8, 4);
    cvSetData(ovImage, pOutputData, ovImage->widthStep);

    Mat img = cvarrToMat(ovImage);
    Mat imgGray;
    cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    threshold(imgGray, imgGray, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    findContours(imgGray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0, 0));

    contours.resize(contours.size());

    for (size_t k = 0; k < contours.size(); k++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[k]), contours[k], 5, true);
        //drawContours(img, contours, k, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, CV_AA, hierarchy, abs(1));
        if (contours[k].size() == 20){
            ++cTriangles;
            drawContours(img, contours, k, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, CV_AA, hierarchy, abs(1));
        }

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get better feedback here if you first do some research, try some things yourself, and then post the issues that you've stumbled on. Also, this is managed, C++ so you might want to update your tags.

Comment: I've added the C# code that works like I want using Emgu.CV but I'm not sure how to port it to this C++ code.

Comment: What parts of the port are you uncertain of? The object model is the same in both languages.

Comment: both of your code fragments look like total horror to me. the 1st is using *managed c++*, the 2nd is using c# on top of the deprecated opencv c-api. if you want to learn opencv's c++ api, - get rid of both.

Comment: What should I be manipulating pOutputData or outputDataBuffer. I've added the code I'm working with.

Comment: AND PLEASE AVOID IPLIMAGES, you must be definitely confused.

Comment: I am confused just because I'm a C++ ID10T. I know this is probably easy for someone that knows it.

Comment: let me start all over. a contour is a `vector<Point>`. your question is about 'smoothing' that? please discard all the code in your question, that won't lead anywhere. let's focus on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to use the findContours method from openCV on the output from the first code block, then use drawContours to add a stroke around the contour and have the original image plus the stroke be the final output. The second code block does exactly what I want it to do but I need it in C++ (first code block).

Answer (score 0):

This is the C# code converted to C++ in the second code block:

```
//.h file code:

using namespace Emgu::CV;
using namespace Emgu::CV::Structure;

namespace Microsoft
{
    namespace Samples
    {
        namespace Kinect
        {
            namespace BodyIndexBasics
            {
                /// <summary>
                /// Class responsible for extracting out the contours of an image.
                /// </summary>
                class FindContours
                {
                    /// <summary>
                    /// Method used to process the image and set the output result images.
                    /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="colorImage">Source color image.</param>
                    /// <param name="thresholdValue">Value used for thresholding.</param>
                    /// <param name="processedGray">Resulting gray image.</param>
                    /// <param name="processedColor">Resulting color image.</param>
                public:
                    void IdentifyContours(Bitmap *colorImage, int thresholdValue, bool invert, Bitmap *&processedGray, Bitmap *&processedColor);
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

//.cpp file code:

using namespace Emgu::CV;
using namespace Emgu::CV::Structure;
namespace Microsoft
{
    namespace Samples
    {
        namespace Kinect
        {
            namespace BodyIndexBasics
            {

                void FindContours::IdentifyContours(Bitmap *colorImage, int thresholdValue, bool invert, Bitmap *&processedGray, Bitmap *&processedColor)
                {

                    BlurBitmapEffect *myBlurEffect = new BlurBitmapEffect();

                    Image<Gray*, unsigned char> *grayImage = new Image<Gray*, unsigned char>(colorImage);
                    Image<Bgr*, unsigned char> *color = new Image<Bgr*, unsigned char>(new Bitmap(colorImage->Width, colorImage->Height));



                    grayImage = grayImage->ThresholdBinary(new Gray(thresholdValue), new Gray(255));
                    if (invert)
                    {
                        grayImage->_Not();
                    }



                    MemStorage *storage = new MemStorage();
                    try
                    {
                        for (Contour<Point> contours = grayImage->FindContours(Emgu::CV::CvEnum::CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD::CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu::CV::CvEnum::RETR_TYPE::CV_RETR_TREE, storage); contours != nullptr; contours = contours->HNext)
                        {
                            Contour<Point> *currentContour = contours->ApproxPoly(contours->Perimeter * 0.015, storage);
                            if (currentContour->BoundingRectangle->Width > 20)
                            {
                                CvInvoke::cvDrawContours(color, contours, new MCvScalar(255), new MCvScalar(255), -1, 5, Emgu::CV::CvEnum::LINE_TYPE::EIGHT_CONNECTED, Point(0, 0));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        if (storage != nullptr)
                        {
                            storage.Dispose();
                        }
                    }



                    processedColor = color->ToBitmap();
                    processedGray = grayImage->ToBitmap();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more of a direct conversion vs a conversion using the C++ native OpenCV library.